# Matlab system() call interrupted by resizing tmux/screen window

Tags: matlab, tmux, gnu-screen

I am executing another program from Matlab using `system()`.
I am using Matlab in `-nodisplay` mode inside a `tmux` session (over `ssh`).
The call to `system()` takes several minutes to execute.
If I resize the `tmux` window (or e.g. split the pane) during this time, then the call is interrupted with the following error:

```
>> system('sleep 10');
Error using system
Unexpected system error: bang: poll [4] Interrupted system call
```

After that, all future calls to `system()` return immediately, without waiting for the process to finish.
I need to restart Matlab to make it work correctly again.

This does *not* happen if I just use Matlab directly in the `ssh` session *without* `tmux`.

How can I prevent this from happening?

#### Other details:

- The same thing happens if the `ssh` connection is lost (e.g. computer sleep and wake).
- I am using `tmux` but the same thing happens in `screen`.
- The system is Ubuntu 14.04, Matlab version 9.2.0.538062 (R2017a).

Comment: Do you get the same error if you use a script which executes `system()`? I can't reproduce your error.

Comment: Yep, it is the same when running a script.

Comment: consider running you system call in a new thread. See java threads in matlab